# Make.com Mapping from Sheets to Monday.com

Tags: make.com

I'm trying to get my data From ABRA flexibee to Google sheets and Monday.com.

I've already set it up to create a new item, now I have to map the columns in Monday to match. However I don't have a clue how to do that in Make.

I think I should use the Array of column values to change. But I don't have a clue how to get it to change based on the string I input.

F.e. if my string in sheets is "done" how do I tell it to change my dropdown to "done" ?

Thank you for any help.

Only tried to do it without mapping which obviously doesn't work.